# I want to get the selected value from List view in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have ArrayList of object (citiesInSpinner) each object have two value(Id, Name)
I have already get it in alert dialog

[image: Like this:]

I use this function to alert dialog:

```js
public void test()
    {
        FillSpinner();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchFligtsActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Select City");
        ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,citiesInSpinner);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        
      /*  alertDialog.setItems(citiesInSpinner, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            /////
        }
       });*/
        alertDialog.show();


        /**/
    }
```

now I want to make something to get the ((ID)) of item (I mean the Id of City) 
I tried to do that but I failed... 
any help Please !!
and thank you

Comment: Use `setOnItemclicklistener` for listView. You can get ID from position wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                            long id) {

                              City city = citiesInSpinner.get(position)
                              //get your id -> city.Id
                        }
                });
```